# Adding rows to tables of datasets?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database

I created a data set within `VS2012` and created some tables for it. But i am unable to fill the tables using `C#`.

This runs without errors:

> ```
> Database1DataSet.LocationRow newLocationRow;
> newLocationRow = database1DataSet.Location.NewLocationRow();
> newLocationRow.LocationID = 1;
> newLocationRow.LocationName = "Test";
> newLocationRow.LocationInfo = "Test";
> database1DataSet.Location.Rows.Add(newLocationRow); //<- i get an error here ONLY if i use a row with a incorrect foreign key.
> this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(database1DataSet);
> ```

When i insert a simple row into a table like this i cannot find it in the database explorer, it still shows a single row with NULL. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: does your dataset have insert scripts set up?

Comment: Not sure, i just added a dataset and added some tables/collumns so perhaps not if it is not default. I have no experience working with SQL in visual studio, i have lots of mysql experience though.

Comment: You would have got the data from somewhere and that adapter has insert, update and delete commands.

Comment: Have you tried `database1DataSet.AcceptChanges()`? More details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.acceptchanges.aspx